# Why is my DefaultHttpContext Session configuration invalidating after (~20 minutes)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session-cookies

The Use Case I have is having a database selection at the Login window where users can choose which database to access (PROD and TEST for example).  I take their selection and Override `OnConfiguring()` in `ApplicationDbContext` (may or maynot be the best way)

The Session setup **works fine** as long as user is active, but I'm presented with (2) different errors depending on what it looks to be is a HttpSession timeout (not expected) and a Session Cookie timeout (expected).

**Why and how can I get the DefaultHttpContext.Session to not drop its "configuration" per error #2?**

1. If I set the idle timeout to 5 minutes, I get this error which is expected and OK due to cookie being removed (string is null)

> **ArgumentNullException: Value Cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')**

2. If I dont set a `UseSession()` idle timeout or make it larger (like 60 minutes), I get this main error I'm having problems with after an inactivity period:

> **InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request.**

--

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpContext.get_Session()
   at Cropware2.Data.ApplicationDbContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) in D:\Projects\Cropware\Cropware2\Data\ApplicationDbContext.cs:line 36
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Set[TEntity]()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.get_UsersSet()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.FindByIdAsync(String userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.FindByIdAsync(String userId)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GetUserAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.ValidateSecurityStampAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator`1.ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

--   Startup.cs

```
ConfigureServices(..)
        
        // services.AddSession();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "TestSession";
            //options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(245); //invalid
            //options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(245);
            //options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
------------------------------
Configure(...)
        app.UseSession(); //before UseEndpoints() and after UserRouting()
```

-- Setting Session at Login for Datasource connection string to be using in ApplicationDBConnect override

```
  AccountController:
 
  [HttpPost]
  Login(...)

       IConfigurationSection connectionString = _configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetChildren().Where(a => a.Key == database).SingleOrDefault();

       HttpContext.Session.SetString("ConnectionName", connectionString.Key);
       HttpContext.Session.SetString("ConnectionString", connectionString.Value);
```

-- This works fine, until I get a Session not configured error after ~20 min

```
ApplicationDbContext:

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

            string ConnectionString = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("ConnectionString");
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
        }
```

-- I've even tried to set this in IIS with multiple different settings in here:

```
<system.web>
     <sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect" cookieName="TestSession" timeout="1440" />
</system.web>
```

-- Other notes

I've also set `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` in `Startup:ConfigureSerivces` and the code works the same whether that line is there or commented out.

-- **UPDATE:**  changed to Cookie instead of Session which may work...

```
        CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();
        option.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1440); //24hours

        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("ConnectionName", connectionString.Key, option);
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("ConnectionString", connectionString.Value, option);
```

[image]

Comment: There is an IIS setting for application pools idle timeout, with a default of 20 minutes. Try setting this to zero: IIS -> Application Pools, select your pool -> advanced settings, search for 'Idle Time-out (minutes)'.

Comment: @nilsK  its already 0, thanks for posting the tip though!